# Excel pivot table default option for new fields - how to change from count to sum

Tags: excel, sum, field, pivot-table, default

I am using MS Excel 2016 to build some pivot tables using a lot of fields.

When I select a new field, it comes as a "count" and not as a "sum" - so I have to change it manually and there is a lot of fields.

My input source has a lot of NULLS / BLANKS - and I believe that is the reason why these new fields are shown initially as "count". Right now, I am changing all the input values from NULL / BLANK to 0 (zero) so the default option changes to "sum".

But I was wondering if there is any other way?

Comment: Nope. You can use code to change all the fields afterwards (that's what I do).

Answer (score 0):

you can check this link, but here is the code (not tested)

```
Public Sub AddPivotDataToSumFields()
    ' Cycles through all pivot data fields and sets to sum
    ' Created by David Sellnow
    ' Version 1.0 November 11 2016

    Dim pf As PivotField
    Dim FieldName As Variant
    Dim TableName As String
    Dim Table As Object
    With Selection.PivotTable
        TableName = .Name
        .ManualUpdate = True
        For Each pf In .DataFields
            With pf
                FieldName = Mid(.Caption, 8)
                ActiveSheet.PivotTables(TableName).AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
                TableName).PivotFields(FieldName), "Max Of " & FieldName, xlMax

                ActiveSheet.PivotTables(TableName).AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
                TableName).PivotFields(FieldName), "Min Of " & FieldName, xlMin

                ActiveSheet.PivotTables(TableName).AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
                TableName).PivotFields(FieldName), "StdDev Of " & FieldName, xlStDev

                ActiveSheet.PivotTables(TableName).AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
                TableName).PivotFields(FieldName), "Var Of " & FieldName, xlVar
            End With
        Next pf
        .ManualUpdate = False
    End With
End Sub
```

http://excelpivots.com/excel/change-multiple-pivot-table-fields-sum-function/